# Can't Anylogic create a Library from a model, which have dependency from another model?

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to export a new custom Library from an my Master model. Export is getting failed if my Master model have a dependency from another Anylogic model. Can't Anylogic create a Library from a model, which have dependency from another model ?

Tried exporting Library from Anylogic model with no errors and successful build.
"Event null" pops up when trying to export the library if it has dependency from another model,

Comment: Maybe try exporting the first model as a library and then accessing it in your project as a library - and then exporting the project as a library.